# Looking for a lite way IIS server for demostrating website

Tags: asp.net, visual-studio, iis

I need to show customer an ASP.NET MVC3 website, but they don't have IIS or Visual Studio installed. only .NET Framework 4 is installed.

So my question is: Is there any tiny little IIS server (like IIS Express), but don't require installation, that can run the compiled site just on local machine?

PS: I don't need advanced features. But HttpHanlders and HttpModules should be working fine.

Comment: Not sure, but you can always install a website on a server, then demonstrate the website that way, rather than installing on the client's computer.

Comment: Bring a laptop running IIS or IIS express?

Comment: @Shan Plourde thanks, but the situation is that the PC is not connected to LAN or Internet, and running Windows 7 Home Basic, so IIS cannot be installed.

Comment: Bring a machine then as John suggested

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I back Shan's suggestion to host your website on a server somewhere and access it over the Internet. I don't see why it wouldn't work for Intranet applications either unless you have dependencies on some services like SMB shares or network printers.

The Cassini ASP.NET webserver is portable and doesn't require installation, but it doesn't run the same as IIS and there are things that will break (because it invokes ASP.NET for every request unlike IIS, so if you've blocked unauthenticated visitors then they wouldn't be able to download site images and stylesheets, for example, until they've logged in).